# JavaScript: Transform and structure array of strings to array of objects

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have an array of strings which is the result of scanning barcodes. It currently looks like this:

```
var array = ['NEW', '1111', 'serial1', 'serial2, 'NEW', '2222', 'serial3', 'serial4'];
```

To process the scanned data I need to transform this array into an array of objects, looking like this:

```
var objects = [
                {
                  order_id: '1111',
                  serial_numbers: ['serial1', 'serial2']
                },
                {
                  order_id: '2222',
                  serial_numbers: ['serial3', 'serial4']
                }
]
```

As you can see, the keyword 'NEW' always indicates, that an `order_id` is coming next (e.g. '1111'). After the `order_id` multiple `serial_numbers` are following until the next 'NEW' entry.

I tried structuring the array with indexes but that didn't work well.

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hi man i would do it the following in way if there is a fixed amount of serial numbers:

```
function parseArray(input) {
  let output = [];
  for (let i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
    if (array[i] === 'NEW') {
      output.push({
        order_id: array[i + 1],
        serial: [array[i + 2], array[i + 3]]
      });
      i += 3;
    }
  }
  return output;
}
```

You can see my stackblitz for a running example: https://stackblitz.com/edit/web-platform-ec4kcw?file=script.js

EDIT:

i changed the function to now also accomodate any lengths of serials:

```
function parseArray(input) {
  let output = [];
  let item = {};
  for (let i = 0; i < input.length; i++) {
    if (input[i] === 'NEW') {
      item = {
        order_id: input[i + 1],
        serial: []
      };
      output.push(item);
      i += 1;
    } else {
      item.serial.push(input[i]);
    }
  }
  return output;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. The amount of serial numbers is not fixed, unfortunately.

Answer (score 2):

You can easily achieve this result using [reduce](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce)

```js
var array = [
  "NEW",
  "1111",
  "serial1",
  "serial2",
  "NEW",
  "2222",
  "serial3",
  "serial4",
];

const result = array.reduce((acc, curr) => {
  if (curr === "NEW") acc.push({ order_id: "", serial_numbers: [] });
  else {
    const last = acc[acc.length - 1];
    if (!last.order_id) last.order_id = curr;
    else last.serial_numbers.push(curr);
  }

  return acc;
}, []);

console.log(result);
```

```css
/* This is not a part of answer. It is just to give the output fill height. So IGNORE IT */
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Answer (score 0):

I would process the unstructured array items to a more suitable format first before constructing objects. Code below,

```js
var array = ['NEW', '1111', 'serial1', 'serial2', 'NEW', '2222', 'serial3', 'serial4'];

// Create an array of array consisting of the serial numbers
// The first item of the array is the order id
function parseOrders(items) {
  const orders = [];
  let orderItems = [];
  
  items.forEach((item) => {
    if (item === 'NEW') {
      if (orderItems.length > 0) {
        orders.push(orderItems);
      }
      orderItems = [];
    } else {
      orderItems.push(item)
    }
  })

  if (orderItems.length > 0) orders.push(orderItems);
  return orders;
}

function transformToObjects(orders) {
  const objects = [];
  orders.forEach((order) => {
    const orderId = order[0];
    const serialNumbers = order.slice(1);
    objects.push({
      order_id: orderId,
      serial_numbers: serialNumbers,
    })
  })
  return objects;
}

const orders = parseOrders(array);
const objects = transformToObjects(orders);
console.log(objects);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
const output = array.reduce((prev,curr,index,arr)=>{
if(curr==='NEW') {
    return prev.concat({
        order_id: arr[index+1],
        serial_numbers: [arr[index+2], arr[index+3]]
    });
}
return prev;
},[]);
```

By using reduce method you can get easily the formatted output.